# Error when creating new recource using backend AWS s3

Tags: terraform, amazon-s3

When I try create a new resource using `terraform apply` (Terraform init was success) received an error:

```
data.terraform_remote_state.environment_data: Refreshing state...

Error: Unable to find remote state

  on backend.tf line 15, in data "terraform_remote_state" "project_data":
  15: data "terraform_remote_state" "project_data" {

No stored state was found for the given workspace in the given backend.


Error: Unable to find remote state

  on backend.tf line 25, in data "terraform_remote_state" "environment_data":
  25: data "terraform_remote_state" "environment_data" {

No stored state was found for the given workspace in the given backend.
```

And here is my point, it's a new resource the Terraform should be create the new tfstate in using my backend configuration in this case AWS S3.

I have this same recipe in use to other resources running...

Anyone can clarify me?

Comment: Post some code please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guys I discovered what happened.
It was necessary to apply these two resources that I informed (project_data and environment_data), but they were in the above directories and I was not aware.

Something like this:

```
Application
|
|-Environment
  |-environment_data.tf
|
|- project_data.tf
```